sqlalchemy to run sql stored procedure with multiple parameters
I am trying to use python - sqlalchemy and pandas - to run a stored procedure on a SQL server and to store the results of that procedure in a dataframe.
Similar to the question here (read_sql_query() using stored procedure and parameters) but I have 2 parameters and I can't get the answer to work for two.
Code is:
    import pandas as pd
    import pyodbc
    import sqlalchemy as sa

    from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
    conn_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc",database=dbname, host=server,  query =           {'Trusted_Connection':'yes','driver':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'})
    Year = 10; Type = 'Loss'
    stored_proc_name = 'dbo.SPTest'
    sql = f"exec {stored_proc_name} @p1 = :param1, @p2 = :param2;"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params={"param1": Year, "param2": Type})

I get the error: ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
I have tried every combination of brackets and punctuation I can think of for the parameters but I can't get the code to take in the 2 parameters.
If I run the code directly in SQL it outputs a table.
If I try the format:
    query = 'EXEC SPTest @year = ?, @loss = ?'
    df = pd.read_sql(query, engine, params=[Year, Type]) 

as suggested here:
How to modify code to execute sql Stored procedure with multiple parameters using Pandas
I get ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries
I am using Python 3.12, sqlalchemy 2.0.35, pyodbc 5.1.0, panda 2.2.2
Any help much appreciated.

did you try wrapping your sql in sqlalchemy.text() ? like in the first link you mentioned

Your second example should work if you pass a tuple (instead of a list) to the params= argument: df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=(Year, Type))

Thank you so much @Gord Thompson! That worked for me.
iBeMelvin - I tried that and got an error. I couldn't get Text to work at all.
